# Force view-port size for print layout with bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

My page presents a form that breaks from horizontal to vertical at `@screen-tablet` which is around ~ 760px. an A4 page width is around ***~600px***.

In my `print.css` I'm shrinking all the text, e.g, `font-size:85%` so that all default font sized 14 will print at around 12. I also want to display the format 
 and it's horizontal state, meaning - `viewport > 760px`. Problem is that the print layout sets the page width at A4 ***~600px*** causing the form to display vertically.

Is there any way to "fool" the layout into thinking it's more than 760px?

(I'm hoping for an answer that doesn't require setting a whole new layout for print - just making it look as it would on desktop).

Comment: Make our job easier and post a example on: www.jsfiddle.net
The response seems easy for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property with a media query [`print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Media_types) type such as:

```
@media print {
  html {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

This will allow you to scale the document without reflow of content.

- **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/pohuski/pen/LpmyyJ)** Example
- [`transform` Functionality Explained](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use the `@media` followed by any of these

`@media screen`, `@media print`,`@media screen, print`

By defining the state of any style at the time of paint you can define every rule on `@media screen, print` which can work for the range in the document.

Like you want to freeze the viewport to 700px then you can define the `@media print` rule for `@media screen,print and (min-width<=760px) { body,html{ min-width:700px;max-width:700px; }}`.
which define and set your viewport to a specific point.

> Note: This rule can also be used for other work like `transform` and
>   `zoom` as an aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this via defining separate `CSS Rules` for print.
You have two options either through `JavaScript` or with `Media query`.

```js
function printForMe()
{
  var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print Proposal', 'height=400,width=600');
  mywindow.document.write('<html><head><style>div{font-size:7pt;display:block;}body{padding:10pt;} .xt-print-box{page-break-inside: avoid !important;} a[href]:after { content:none !important; }</style>');
  mywindow.document.write($("head").html()); //Skip this line if you want to completely rewrite the styles and scripts therein header.
  mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
  mywindow.document.write($("#myContent").html());
  mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
  mywindow.print();
}
```

```css
@media print { 
  div{font-size:7pt;display:block;}
  body{padding:10pt;} 
  .xt-print-box{page-break-inside: avoid !important;} 
  a[href]:after { content:none !important; }
}
```